# How to add a choices Field that will list currencies from babel

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I came across `babel` [documentation](http://babel.pocoo.org/en/latest/index.html) and I would like to use it in a model that has a `currencies = models.ChoiceField`. How do I use babel inbuilt currencies to list in the above field name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Babel for that you can try something like this:

```
from babel.numbers import list_currencies
CURRENCY_CHOICES = [(currency, currency) for currency in list_currencies()] 
# `choices` has to be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple) consisting
# itself of iterables of exactly two items from which first of values is
# stored in database and the second is for representation.
class ModelName(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, null=True, blank=True, choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES
    )
    currency_with_default = models.CharField(
        max_length=3, default='USD', choices=CURRENCY_CHOICES
    )
```

Comment: There is a NameError: name 'x' is not defined